# Can't get some buttons to work

Tags: javascript, html, css

Below is some code I need to fix. I fixed some of the errors, but I cant get the 3 buttons to work. They are the random facts buttons, the colors orange pink and green button, and the grow and shrink button.

I posted the code below, the html seems right to me, and the css too. I am betting on the Javascript to be wrong for the buttons, but I just don't see what part of it could be incorrect. This is due to my inexperience but I am pretty sure I fixed all the HTML errors.

```js
$("#factButton").on("click", function() {
  var number = Math.floor((Math.random() * booFacts.length));
  $("#factText").text(booFacts[number])
})

var booFacts = ["Boo is a pomeranian, Boo's best friend is another pomeranian named Buddy, Boo the Pomeranian was born on March 16, making him a Pisces, Boo's favourite food is grass, Boo has released two books"]

$("#textPink").on("click", function() {
  $("#funText").css("color", pink)
})


$("#textOrange").on("click", function() {
  $("#funText").css("color", "orange")
})
$("#textGreen").on("click", function() {
  $("#funText").css("color", "green")
})


$("#boxGrow").on(click, function() {
  $("#box").animate({
    height: "+=35px",
    width: "+=35px"
  }, "fast");
})

$("#boxShrink").on(click, function() {
  $("#box").animate({
    height: "-=35px",
    width: "-=35px"
  }, "fast");
})
```

```css
.jumbotron {
  background-color: #428bca
}

.jumbotron h1 {
  color: white;
}

p,
h1,
h4 {
  font-family: 'Roboto Slab', serif;
}

#funText {
  color: black;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-family: 'Roboto Slab', serif;
}

#box {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Boo The Dog</title>
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <!-- Linking CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <!-- Linking jQuery -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Linking Google Fonts -->
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat|Roboto+Slab|Yellowtail' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">

    <div class="jumbotron bg-primary text-center">
      <h1>Boo The Dog Fan Page!</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="panel panel-primary">
          <div class="panel-heading">Instructions</div>
          <div class="panel-body text-center">
            <!--<h4>Oh no! Someone has vandalized our Boo 'The Cutest Dog In The World' fanpage!</h4>
        <h4>There are a bunch of errors on this page!</h4>
        <h4>Try your best to find them all!</h4> -->
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="panel panel-primary">
          <div class="panel-heading">About Boo</div>
          <div class="panel-body">
            Boo the dog belongs to a San Francisco-based Facebook employee who created a Facebook page for the dog with a statement "My name is Boo. I am a dog. Life is good." He became popular in October 2010 after singer Ke$ha sent a tweet that she had a new boyfriend,
            linking to the page. Chronicle Books, noticing that Boo had 5 million Facebook fans at the time, approached the owner to write a picture book. In August 2011, Boo: The Life of the World's Cutest Dog, written by his owner under pen name J.H.
            Lee, was published. The book was eventually published in ten languages. A second book followed, Boo: Little Dog in the Big City, as well as a calendar and plans for a cut-out book and additional children's books. He also has his own stuffed
            animal for kids. His merchandise includes a Gund stuffed animal. Boo was appointed a spokesdog for Virgin America airline, which featured photos of him in an airplane along with advice for people traveling with pets. In April 2012, Boo was
            the subject of a death hoax after #RIPBOO appeared on Facebook. Tweets followed as Gizmodo writer Sam Biddle tweeted Boo had died. It was later confirmed by The Chronicle Book staff that Boo was alive and well. In July 2012, Boo was named
            the Official Pet Liaison of Virgin America. Read more at: <a href="">https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boo_(dog)</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="well text-center">
          <div>
            <img class="img-responsive" src="https://img.buzzfeed.com/buzzfeed-static/static/2015-04/21/16/enhanced/webdr05/enhanced-31550-1429646952-7.jpg">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <br><br>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6 text-center">
        <button class="btn btn-primary form-control" id="factButton">Random Boo Fact</button>
        <div class="well text-center">
          <div>
            <p id="factText">Click the button for a random Boo fact!</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="panel panel-primary">
          <div class="panel-heading">List Of Boo's Favorite Things</div>
          <div class="panel-body">
            <ol>
              Dressing Up Eating Grass Sleeping Swimming Hiking
            </ol>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <br><br>

    <div class="row text-center">

      <div class="col-sm-6 text-center">
        <button class="btn" id="textOrange">Orange</button>
        <button class="btn" id="textPink">Pink</button>
        <button class="btn" id="textGreen">Green</button>
        <div class="well text-center">
          <p id="funText">Boo Rules!</p>
        </div>

      </div>

      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <button class="btn" id="boxGrow">Grow</button>
          <button class="btn" id="boxShrink">Shrink</button>
          <div class="well text-center">
            <img id="box" src="http://petradioshow.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/jiff1.jpg" style="display: inline-block; height: 205px; width: 205px;">
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>

    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="errors.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put pink color in "

```
$("#funText").css("color", "pink");
```

Also put "click" events in " too

```
$("#boxGrow").on("click", function() {

$("#box").animate({
    height: "+=35px",
    width: "+=35px"
  }, "fast");
})

$("#boxShrink").on("click", function() {
  $("#box").animate({
    height: "-=35px",
    width: "-=35px"
  }, "fast");
})
```

Full code

```js
$("#factButton").on("click", function() {
  var number = Math.floor((Math.random() * booFacts.length));
  $("#factText").text(booFacts[number])
})

var booFacts = ["Boo is a pomeranian, Boo's best friend is another pomeranian named Buddy, Boo the Pomeranian was born on March 16, making him a Pisces, Boo's favourite food is grass, Boo has released two books"]

$("#textPink").on("click", function() {
  $("#funText").css("color", "pink")
})


$("#textOrange").on("click", function() {
  $("#funText").css("color", "orange")
})
$("#textGreen").on("click", function() {
  $("#funText").css("color", "green")
})


$("#boxGrow").on("click", function() {
  $("#box").animate({
    height: "+=35px",
    width: "+=35px"
  }, "fast");
})

$("#boxShrink").on("click", function() {
  $("#box").animate({
    height: "-=35px",
    width: "-=35px"
  }, "fast");
})
```

```css
.jumbotron {
  background-color: #428bca
}

.jumbotron h1 {
  color: white;
}

p,
h1,
h4 {
  font-family: 'Roboto Slab', serif;
}

#funText {
  color: black;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-family: 'Roboto Slab', serif;
}

#box {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Boo The Dog</title>
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <!-- Linking CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <!-- Linking jQuery -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Linking Google Fonts -->
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat|Roboto+Slab|Yellowtail' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">

    <div class="jumbotron bg-primary text-center">
      <h1>Boo The Dog Fan Page!</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="panel panel-primary">
          <div class="panel-heading">Instructions</div>
          <div class="panel-body text-center">
            <!--<h4>Oh no! Someone has vandalized our Boo 'The Cutest Dog In The World' fanpage!</h4>
                <h4>There are a bunch of errors on this page!</h4>
                <h4>Try your best to find them all!</h4> -->
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="panel panel-primary">
          <div class="panel-heading">About Boo</div>
          <div class="panel-body">
            Boo the dog belongs to a San Francisco-based Facebook employee who created a Facebook page for the dog with a statement "My name is Boo. I am a dog. Life is good." He became popular in October 2010 after singer Ke$ha sent a tweet that she had a new boyfriend,
            linking to the page. Chronicle Books, noticing that Boo had 5 million Facebook fans at the time, approached the owner to write a picture book. In August 2011, Boo: The Life of the World's Cutest Dog, written by his owner under pen name J.H.
            Lee, was published. The book was eventually published in ten languages. A second book followed, Boo: Little Dog in the Big City, as well as a calendar and plans for a cut-out book and additional children's books. He also has his own stuffed
            animal for kids. His merchandise includes a Gund stuffed animal. Boo was appointed a spokesdog for Virgin America airline, which featured photos of him in an airplane along with advice for people traveling with pets. In April 2012, Boo was
            the subject of a death hoax after #RIPBOO appeared on Facebook. Tweets followed as Gizmodo writer Sam Biddle tweeted Boo had died. It was later confirmed by The Chronicle Book staff that Boo was alive and well. In July 2012, Boo was named
            the Official Pet Liaison of Virgin America. Read more at: <a href="">https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boo_(dog)</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="well text-center">
          <div>
            <img class="img-responsive" src="https://img.buzzfeed.com/buzzfeed-static/static/2015-04/21/16/enhanced/webdr05/enhanced-31550-1429646952-7.jpg">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <br><br>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6 text-center">
        <button class="btn btn-primary form-control" id="factButton">Random Boo Fact</button>
        <div class="well text-center">
          <div>
            <p id="factText">Click the button for a random Boo fact!</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="panel panel-primary">
          <div class="panel-heading">List Of Boo's Favorite Things</div>
          <div class="panel-body">
            <ol>
              Dressing Up Eating Grass Sleeping Swimming Hiking
            </ol>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <br><br>

    <div class="row text-center">

      <div class="col-sm-6 text-center">
        <button class="btn" id="textOrange">Orange</button>
        <button class="btn" id="textPink">Pink</button>
        <button class="btn" id="textGreen">Green</button>
        <div class="well text-center">
          <p id="funText">Boo Rules!</p>
        </div>

      </div>

      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <button class="btn" id="boxGrow">Grow</button>
          <button class="btn" id="boxShrink">Shrink</button>
          <div class="well text-center">
            <img id="box" src="http://petradioshow.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/jiff1.jpg" style="display: inline-block; height: 205px; width: 205px;">
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>

    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="errors.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I do not understand could you please explain, the pink color is already in the JS

Comment: You add word `pink` and it does not make any sense in JS code. You must put `"pink"` instead to be used as a color. @J1N1

Comment: Put these words in double quotes just. @J1N1

Comment: green and orange are in " but they do not work either and click is in " in green and Orange but it does not seem to be work there is something else wrong?

Comment: Did you check the snippet? They change the color of text correctly. Did you add jquery to project? Check the browser console and give the error @J1N1

Comment: I checked the snippet and inputted into my text editor but the issues that adding " to pink does not work nor does add " click into the JS as you can see in the snippets I posted " was already in click and it did not work

Comment: Does my answer works well?? your snippet still has `$("#boxGrow").on(click, function() {`. the **click** must be in double quotes @J1N1

Comment: Did you get the problem?? @J1N1 If not prepare a codepen and i'll help you on your own code.

Comment: thank you for the help I finally got it there was an issue with my personal system that caused the issue that I got confused I really thank you for your patience and assistance